# Why does standard library min function shows error below?

Tags: c++, error-handling, min

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    
    int maximumProduct(vector<int>& nums) {
        
        int n = nums.size();        
        vector<long long int> left_max(n,0);
        vector<long long int> right_max(n,0);
        vector<long long int> left_min(n,0);
        vector<long long int> right_min(n,0);
        
        left_min[0]=nums[0];
        left_max[0]=nums[0];
        cout<<max(1,5); //this line is working 
        for(int i=1;i<nums.size();i++){
            left_min[i]=min(left_min[i-1],nums[i]); // why this line is throwing error
            left_max[i]=max(left_max[i-1],nums[i]);
        }

        right_min[n-1] = nums[n-1];
        right_max[n-1] = nums[n-1];
        
        for(int i=n-2;i>=0;i++){
            right_min[i]=min(nums[i],right_min[i+1]);
            right_max[i]=max(nums[i],right_max[i+1]);
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            cout<<right_min[i]<<" ";
        }
        return 1;
    }
};
```

Above I have commented two line one is showing error and one is not ? can someone explain it?

Error Message below:

```
Line 16: Char 25: error: no matching function for call to 'min'
            left_min[i]=min(left_min[i-1],nums[i]); // why this line is throwing error
                        ^~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/algorithmfwd.h:383:5: note: candidate template ignored: deduced conflicting types for parameter '_Tp' ('long long' vs. 'int')
    min(const _Tp&, const _Tp&);
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:3450:5: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'initializer_list<type-parameter-0-0>' against 'long long'
    min(initializer_list<_Tp> __l, _Compare __comp)
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:3444:5: note: candidate function template not viable: requires single argument '__l', but 2 arguments were provided
    min(initializer_list<_Tp> __l)
    ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/algorithmfwd.h:388:5: note: candidate function template not viable: requires 3 arguments, but 2 were provided
    min(const _Tp&, const _Tp&, _Compare);
    ^
```

Comment: The error might be in the code not shown. Please provide a complete working code.

Comment: What's the error you got?

Comment: When asking questions about build errors, *always* include the full and complete copy-paste of the errors (as text). Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: In your second loop `i` only reaches zero with vectors of size one or less, as it starts from `n - 2` and gets higher and higher, but it cannot even hit integer overload, as the UB caused by index out-of-range (segfault most likely) would happen much earlier than that.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing two different types, `int` and `long long int` to `min` and `max`. Those functions expect both arguments to be the same type.

You can try casting the `int` argument to `long long int`.

Comment: Or maybe simply declare the four vectors to have elements of type `int`, as min and max wouldn't exceed `int` range.

Comment: It worked ..Thankns !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Or give an explicit type: `std::min<long long>(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

The data type of `left_min` and `nums` are different, that's why you are getting error. Try to define all vector of the same data type.